# how do we load huge attachments to salesforce content

Tags: apex, data-loader, informatica, etl

i am looking to load multiple huge video files (100MB x 10) in separate files into the content object in salesforce. I intend to load the files into a particular library which is already existing.

Now as per the documentation i see that there is a limitation of 37 MB if content loaded via API. I am little puzzled on this limitation, does that mean i can never use any ETL tool to upload bulky content into salesforce, since salesforce is so widely used, how is this scenario currently managed. Are we expected to manually upload bulky content?

Answer (score 1):

You are right SFDC can not host such a big files. To store such big files you should specialized cloud service like Amazon s3 (or host your won) and provide URL of that resource in your object.

for more details on salesforce limits refer this document.

https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf